# Why is Spark sending all tasks to two executors?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Here's a picture of the situation:

[image]

My code:

```
rdd = spark.read.format("avro").load(paths).rdd.repartition(160).flatMap(parse_source_data).repartition(20)
```

`parse_source_data` is an expensive Python function that gets mapped over all data. I'm seeing 160 total tasks as expected. Spark claims that 80 are running concurrently, as expected. But in actuality, it appears that all tasks are being run by two executors.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: How did you submit job?

Answer (score 0):

I was creating a SparkContext on the workers. This prevented the workers from being used for the actual job.

Comment: https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/67604/how-to-get-sparkcontext-in-executor.html